# Unexpected end of form at Multipart._final- next js and multer error

Tags: javascript, file, next.js, multer

I have been trying to upload pdfs and save it in backend using multer in next js. now the payload does go to backend
[image: payload from frontend]
but the problem is it doesnt store file in public/uploads. In fact I'm unable to access it at all.

[image: backend]

here undefined is me trying to access file and above it is a error .

that being said if I console log req.body i get this
[image: I'm console loging req.body]

### what do i do to

1. access file from backend
2. store it in 'public/uploads'

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const FileUploader = () => {
    const [file, setFile] = useState(null);

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setFile(event.target.files[0]);
        console.log(event.target.files[0]);
    };

    const handleUpload = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (!file) {
            alert('Please select a file before uploading.');
            return;
        }

        try {
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', file);

            const response = await fetch('/api/hello', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData,
            });

            if (response.ok) {
                alert('File uploaded successfully!');
            } else {
                alert('Failed to upload the file. Please try again.');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error uploading the file:', error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <form encType="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <input
                type="file"
                name="file"
                accept="application/pdf"
                onChange={handleChange}
            />
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" onClick={handleUpload} />
        </form>
    );
};

export default FileUploader;
```

this is my frontend code

```
import multer from 'multer';
const upload=()=>multer({
    storage: multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './public/uploads')
      },
      filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
      }
    })

  })


export default function handler(req, res) {
  
  upload().single('file')(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
      console.log(err)
    } else if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
    console.log(req.file)
  })


  res.status(200).json({ name: 'John Doe' })
}
```

this is my backend code

if i add

```
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                },
```

as mentioned in one of answers I was searching ( in chatgpt ). I'll get a diffrent error saying Multipart: Boundary not found.

I have also tried watching this youtube channel [youtube](https://youtu.be/XC5rdgxyioY) but also tried to see other channels. the downside is they are telling how to solve in node js and for next js there aren't many resources I could find